# URL rewrite of an multitenant application using IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting, iis-7, iis-7.5

For a multitenant application, I want to redirect URL with **www to non-www** URL from the **URL rewrite** feature.
I added several rules to the web.config file as follows.

```
   <rule name="Redirect to non www main domain" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.test.com" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://test.com/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    
    <rule name="Force non-WWW" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(www\.)(.*)$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:2}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
    
    <rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
```

These rules covers every scenarios except only one scenario for subdomains.

> http://subdomain.tezt1.com ==> https://subdomain.tezt1.com (OK) 
> http://www.subdomain.tezt1.com ==> https://subdomain.tezt1.com (OK) 
> [www.subdomain.tezt1.com](http://www.subdomain.tezt1.com) ==> https://subdomain.tezt1.com (OK) 
> https://subdomain.tezt1.com ==> https://subdomain.tezt1.com (OK) 
> https://www.subdomain.tezt1.com ==> (NOT OK) [Expect - https://subdomain.tezt1.com]

What could be the problem for this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules FRT can tell you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove www, you can try this rule:

```
<rule name="Remove WWW" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url=".*" ignoreCase="true" />
     <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
       <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.(.*)$" />
     </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:1}/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Yes I have done the same thing as you mentioned and I managed to remove the www from the URL. But my concern is when the request is with the SSL (https). It's not working.

Comment: You can try it, if you get any problems, please come to discuss.